# How to resize navigation bar button images

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, frame, cgrect

I have tried the other stack overflow answers and they don't seem to work, I am not sure if something has changed in swift 5. But here is the code I used to create the right bar button. I followed a tutorial on youtube, and then looked to stackoverflow for solutions, and none seem to work. As I have set the frame for the button to be 34x34 yet the image seems to just stretch across the whole navigation bar.

```
        //Adding Unmatch Button
        let unmatchBtn = UIButton(type: .system)
        unmatchBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "heartbreak")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal )
        unmatchBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: unmatchBtn)
```

[image]

edit:

With the help of the answer it now fits properly on the nav bar, the layout is now messed up though. The stuff to its left is a customview that I made which is being pushed to the left. 
[image]

Comment: i always use uiivew and uibutton to avoid this type of problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let item = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: ImageNameHere), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))

@objc func action() {

}
```

Comment: Awesome this worked, but now it is in the middle of the nav bar, instead of my right. Any idea what I could do to fix this? I edited my post to add a picture of what it looks like now. I thought perhaps I could fix this with anchors but it seems that the "item" variable doesn't have anchor properties.

Comment: @Wana_B3_Nerd 
Check this: 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-flexible-space-to-a-uibarbuttonitem

Comment: I tried that, but it ends up moving the picture and label to the far left, and the heart remains in the middle